# asp.net MVC3 global route and hardcoded routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have an application that I am using a global route to query for the current path and return page specific data. I have the routes setup like this...

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Pages",
            "Pages",
            new { controller = "Pages", action = "Index" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Navigation",
            "Navigation",
            new {controller = "Navigation", action = "Index"});

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{*url}", // URL with parameters {controller}/{action}/{id}
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

The problem I am facing is when I go to /Pages to try and add new pages, the PageController fires like it is supposed to, but when debugging, after going to /Pages the app then makes a request for the HomeController. Am I missing something in my routing setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Default route is firing because of the {*url}. So any page that's not /Pages, will go to the default route.

I need more info, but if you're trying to do /Pages/whatever, then you need to add an optional parameter on your Pages route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "Pages",
       "Pages/{page}",
       new { controller = "Pages", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your default route is incorrect.  It should look like the default route as defined when you open a new MVC 3 project, like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "Default", // Route name
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

The problem is that the default route you defined will not parse any requests which reach it.